# WCF central service with multiple clients

Tags: wcf, client-server

i can't find any good architecture explanation of how can WCF SHOULD be part of a main-server with multiple clients.
in my solution, i want to have a central WCF service (hosted in windows-service on windows server machine).
The central service is the only one that's connected to the DB.
all the clients, are connecting to this main service, login, and get having a duplex communication.
via that main service, one client can connect another one. or when one client using the main service to change the DB, the main service updates all other clients.

for doing that, i added in the main service the `InstanceContextMode.Single` attribute, and in the windows-service, i init ServiceHost with the WCF-service singleton.

it works. so so..
i can continue and search where the problems are, and how to fix them, but it looks like something here is not right, like i'm not supposed to do it this way.

i could really use an advice on how WCF service should be used as a main service with multiple clients, that require common memory. 
it's basically for ~20 clients with not too intensive operations, but i still want the option to let them all communicate simultaneously with the main service, and not only one by one.

Comment: if i understand right, then client1 and client2 will connect to different instances. how can i have one main-instance that according to a certain event, will send a callback message to all clients?
or should i just use static "containers" for common memory?

Comment: and that's the difference between what i CAN and what i SHOULD do. it's very simple when we're talking about standalone web-service <--> client . but i want is one client-application to connect other client-application. i want to create a gui-app that logs-in the main server and get SW/HW status from all its clients.
i'm looking for a good architecture for a solution with shared-communication between all the components. so "singleton" and "static" sounds bad, but PerCall is not designed for that either.

Comment: Is sounds like you're looking for a publish-subscribe design. There's quite a few examples on the web of how to do that with WCF - here's one example:  http://www.anujvarma.com/series/wcf-publish-subscribe-c/